# Node.js Express Passport Cookie Expiration

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am using Passport for authentication in my app, and I am also using Express. To summarize my issue: **my login functionality works fine initially, but after *any* user's session times out, *no* users are able to log in.**

I am using the standard Local strategy for authentication.

I'll include as bare an example as possible based on my setup:

```
//-------------
//Set up authentication with Passport
//-------------
var userModel = require('./models/user')(db);
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        var errorMessage = 'Incorrect username/password combination.';
        userModel.GetUserByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) {
              return done(null, false, { message: errorMessage });
            }

            user.validatePassword(password, function(isPasswordCorrect) {
                if (!isPasswordCorrect)
                {
                    return done(null, false, { message: errorMessage });
                }

                //Update with login date
                userModel.UpdateUserWithLogin(username, user.currentLoginTime, function(err){
                    //if we have an error here, we should probably just log it
                    if(err)
                    {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });

                return done(null, user);
            });
        });
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    userModel.GetUserByUsername(user._id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
});

//-------------
//Set up express and configure
//-------------
var sessionStore = new SkinStore(db);
var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.engine('html', consolidate.swig);
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    swig.init({
        root: '.',
        allowErrors: true, // allows errors to be thrown and caught by express instead of suppressed
        autoescape: false});

    app.use(express.logger('dev'));

    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.cookieParser("[mysecrethere]"));
    app.use(express.session({   store: sessionStore,
                            cookie: { expires : new Date(Date.now() + 3600000) } //1 Hour
                            }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(flash());
    app.use(expressValidator);

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    //Dynamic helpers
    app.use(require('./helpers/DynamicHelpers'));

    app.use(app.router);
});

app.get('/login', routes.login);
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {failureRedirect: '/login',
                                               badRequestMessage: "Please enter username and password",
                                               failureFlash: true }),
                                               function(req, res) {
                                                    var targetUrl = req.session.pageAfterLogin;
                                                    delete req.session.pageAfterLogin;
                                                    res.redirect(targetUrl || '/account');
                                                });

app.get('/account', IsAuthenticated, routes.account.show);
```

And the IsAuthenticated helper function:

```
function IsAuthenticated(req,res,next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated())
    {
        next();
    }
    else
    {
        //save the requested page and then redirected
        req.session.pageAfterLogin = req.url;
        req.flash("error", "You must be logged in first!");
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

What I can find by debugging is that, after successful authentication (and after a cookie has expired), I hit this logic (from above):

```
function(req, res) {
    var targetUrl = req.session.pageAfterLogin;
    delete req.session.pageAfterLogin;
    res.redirect(targetUrl || '/account');
}
```

Where I can see that the "req" has the session properly set, with Passport information stored properly. Then, the redirect happens, the **new** request has no session information stored, and has an entirely new Session ID. I suspected that no cookie was being set on the client, and that does appear to be the case, which should explain the lack of consistent sessions.

However, I cannot figure out **why** no new cookie is being set. Is there something wrong with how the app is configured that would indicate why this is happening?

I should add that restarting the Node.js instance fixes the issue, it's just not something that would be tolerable in production.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: I ran Fiddler to see what was happening with HTTP/S traffic, and I can see that when it works initially, I'm getting a cookie set in the browser (I tried several) which is then passed back to the server on subsequent requests.

When it **doesn't** work, the browser is not passing cookies to the server, and so Node is sending a Set-Cookie header that provides a new cookie each time. So far I've had no luck determining the cause of this.

Comment: Have you checked that passport.deserializeUser is run, that user._id exists and that your model finds the user? Also serializeUser should callback an id, not the user object.

Comment: I was able to test this out (finally), and I can see that serializeUser **is** getting called. However, in subsequent redirects, deserializeUser is not getting run. In serializeUser, the user was found properly, it just doesn't seem to persist. And I will work to serialize the user._id instead of the user. I had done that originally but switched for some reason I've since forgotten.

Comment: FYI: according to official documentation (https://github.com/expressjs/session):
   The expires option should not be set directly; instead only use the maxAge option.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I figured it out, although I don't love the answer.

tl;dr; - use maxAge instead of expires.

---

The issue was rooted in the expiration date set on each cookie (which is automatically set by Express). I noticed that every cookie that was set had the same expiration date, which eventually ended up being in the past and hence instantly expiring.

The cause of that was here:

```
cookie: { expires : new Date(Date.now() + 3600000) }
```

The new Date was being created only once, upon server start. That was causing the expiration date to be the same every time. Based on code in the original post, I can't figure out why it doesn't work and yet every example I've found online uses the exact same code. I verified this by defining a function that created this Date, and checking that it only got called upon server start.

To fix this issue, I am defining maxAge instead of "expires". maxAge takes a number of milliseconds, rather than a date, and it appears to be setting the expiration date on all cookies correctly.

**I would love to hear if anyone can explain why this is happening in the first place, since others seem to use it successfully. Any thoughts?**

See my working code below

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.engine('html', consolidate.swig);
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    swig.init({
        root: '.',
        allowErrors: true, // allows errors to be thrown and caught by express instead of suppressed
        autoescape: false});

    app.use(express.logger('dev'));

    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.cookieParser("[mysecrethere]"));
    app.use(express.session({   store: sessionStore,
                            cookie: { maxAge : 3600000 } //1 Hour
                            }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(flash());
    app.use(expressValidator);

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    //Dynamic helpers
    app.use(require('./helpers/DynamicHelpers'));

    app.use(app.router);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @creativename. I've been struggling with this problem for days. After finding out that passport didn't update the expires property I thought it would be impossible. But your solution works like a charm!

Comment: I believe I am running into this issue as well, affecting users in a timezone on the other side of the world.

Comment: a bit off topic but does anyone know if the serializeUser method which passport uses to store the user in the cookie is cryptographically secure?  It isn't just writing IDs to the cookie is it?

Comment: Also check the documentation for "rolling" flag. rolling - Force a cookie to be set on every response.  This resets the expiration date. The default value is false.

https://github.com/expressjs/session#rolling

Answer (score -3):

Set cookie name to value, where which may be a string or object converted to JSON. The path option defaults to "/".

`res.cookie('rememberme', '1', { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000), httpOnly: true });`

The maxAge option is a convenience option for setting "expires" relative to the current time in milliseconds. The following is equivalent to the previous example.

`res.cookie('rememberme', '1', { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true })`

Also the Link

http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.cookie