# Why is my req.user always null on load?

Tags: node.js, session, express, passport.js

I have been struggling for a couple of days and I have made some good progress, but I can't get my session stuff to work quite right.

I have successfully used Passport to authenticate with Facebook. When I click on my login with FB button, the session is loaded perfectly and I have my req.user object all ready to go, but it seems to me that I should only have to do that once.

I know passport saves a cookie. I have looked it up and seen that working.

I am trying to detect if the user is already logged in on the load of my index page, but when I load the page the req.user object is always null and my passport.deserializeUser method never gets called to load it (if I click the log into FB button it does get called).

So my question is, how do you tell passport on page load to check the cookie and load up the user session if there is one?

---

**Update** - Ok, so for those finding this question at a later date, I just wanted to go over what I learned here (thanks to those of you who commented). Hopefully it will help someone else down the line.

I am used to .NET cookies which live regardless of a server. Node.js and passport don't work on the same premise. By default node.js uses a memorystore to keep its session. When you shut down node in terminal/command line (which you have to do each time you change your server code), the memorystore cookie information is reset and therefore any cookies tied to it are meaningless.

To fix this, I installed Redis (http://cook.coredump.me/post/18886668039/brew-install-redis) and hooked it up as my store (http://www.hacksparrow.com/use-redisstore-instead-of-memorystore-express-js-in-production.html).

This will work on Azure which is my planned production server so all is well.

---

Ok, here is some code. I am not sure what parts to put up...

**This is server.js**

```
/**
* Module dependencies.
*/

var express = require('express')
, app = express()
, partials = require('express-partials')
, http = require('http')
, server = http.createServer(app)
, io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
, routes = require('./routes')
// facebook
, passport = require('passport')
, facebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy
// custom stuff
, urlCommand = require('./middleware/UrlCommand')
, azureCommand = require('./middleware/AzureCommand')
, userCommand = require('./middleware/UserCommand');

// Ports
var port = process.env.port;

if (isNaN(port))
  port = 3000;

server.listen(port);

//allows the use of Layouts
app.use(partials());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.RowKey);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    console.log("deserialize");
    userCommand.findByID(id, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

// Configuration
app.configure(function () {
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'SECRET!' }));
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());  
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// Facebook
passport.use(new facebookStrategy({
    clientID: CLIENT,
    clientSecret: "SECRET",
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback" //DEV
},
  function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      userCommand.findOrCreate(profile.id, profile.name.givenName,   profile.name.familyName, profile.emails[0].value, accessToken, function (error, user) {
          return done(null, user);
      });
  }
));

// Routes
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: 'email' }));
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', { successRedirect:   '/',
                                                                   failureRedirect: '/login' }));

// Sockets
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // when the client emits 'sendURL', this listens and executes
    socket.on('sendURL', function (data) {
        console.log('sendURL called: ' + data);
        urlCommand.AddURL(data);

        // we tell the client to execute 'processURL'
        io.sockets.emit('urlComplete', data);
    });
});

console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", port, app.settings.env);
```

**index.js**

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.user); // ALWAYS NULL
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' })
};
```

**UserCommand**

```
var azureCommand = require('../middleware/AzureCommand');
var tableService = azureCommand.CreateTableService();

function findByID(id, callback) {
    console.log('FindByID');

    tableService.queryEntity('user', 'user', id, function (error, entity) {
        console.log('Found him: ' + entity.Email);
        callback(error, entity);
    });
}

function findOrCreate(id, first, last, email, accessToken, callback) {
    var user = {
        PartitionKey: 'user'
        , RowKey: id
        , First: first
        , Last: last
        , Email: email
        , AccessToken: accessToken
   }

    tableService.insertEntity('user', user, function (error) {
        callback(null, user);
    });
}

exports.findByID = findByID;
exports.findOrCreate = findOrCreate;
```

**This is what my output log shows when I output my session...**

```
node server.js
info  - socket.io started
Express server listening on port 3000 in development mode
{ cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true },
  passport: {} 
}
debug - served static content /socket.io.js
```

Comment: It sounds like you might have an incorrect expiry on your session cookies, but please show code (esp. your app and Passport configuration) because otherwise I'd just be guessing.

Comment: without code it's impossible to tell you what's wrong. Have you checked the [example](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/tree/master/examples/login) comes with passport-facebook

Comment: You write *"if I click the log into FB button it does get called"* about `deserializeUser`. Which route is called when you call that button? And `deserializeUser` is just never called for the `/` route, or it just doesn't work? Since you're not handling errors in the `FacebookStrategy` callback, could that be an issue?

Comment: Hey Robert, I don't believe this issue is with FB. That seems to be working correctly. I can authenticate and get my session to work fine when I click on the authorization button. The problem is when a user returns and has already authenticated and stored that as a cookie. I want the site to recognize them on the / route. Currently that isn't working...nothing is getting called to set that up and I don't know how to force it.

Comment: You're storing `user.RowKey` in the session, so `deserializeUser` will call `findById` using that row key as an id; is that how your database works?

Comment: @robertklep Yes sir, that is exactly how that works. RowKey is a special field in all Azure table storage rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` functions.

As you noticed, when you click the FBlogin button `deserializeUser` is called for the first and only time - actually it's called with a `id` that has been before returned just before by `serializeUser` function. If at this moment it will not be able to find the user by the `id` provided, `passport.user` will not be saved into the session.

As a consequence, in following requests `passport.deserializeUser` isn't called at all because `express.session` doesn't fills `req.session` with the passport's user id.

**To sum up**: you need to check if your `serializeUser` returns an `id` than can be understood and  deserialized by your `deserializeUser`.

FYI: a correct `req.user` object for a authenticated user should look like this:

```
{ 
   cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null,  originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true },
   passport: { user: 51772291b3367f0000000001 } 
}
```

Comment: So I put in a console.log to see if my serialize method was being called at all...it is not unless I click my FB button. When I click the FB button it gets called, then my deserialize gets called, and everything works. Another experiment showed me that if I close my browser down and come back the session still works. If I restart my server it is gone. This makes me think that somehow my cookie is session based. How can I update the cookie passport makes so that it lasts for longer than a session?

Comment: FYI: Here is an output of my cookie. Cookie: {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":35999999,"expires":"2013-04-25T08:48:38.994Z","httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"passport":{"user":"775119337"}}. I added MaxAge to it based on this post, but it didn't help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016551/node-js-express-passport-cookie-expiration

Comment: @David since you're not using a session store, Express will default to using the `MemoryStore` to store sessions in, which means that once your server is restarted, sessions are gone. You should either use a persistent store (like [connect-mongo](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo)) or, alternatively, use [cookie-based sessions](http://expressjs.com/api.html#cookieSession).

Comment: @robertklep So the cookie gets blown away too? I understood that my session would get blown away, but I figured that, by default, the cookie would be around for the next load. No?

Comment: @David the cookie should persist, but its contents will be meaningless  (the cookie is not where the id/RowKey is stored, it's stored in the session object; the cookie will only contain a key with which to retrieve the session object from the session store)

Comment: Thanks @robertklep. I installed RedisStore and all is well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The answer didn't really solve my problem, but it started the conversation which did. If you are reading this later, check my update above.

Answer (score -1):

Well, at first you should post some code because the problem could be anywhere.

Than check the beautiful documentation http://passportjs.org/guide/

Despite passport brings a lot of examples via github to you.

If you want to have an complete example with different authentication methods you should visit https://github.com/madhums/nodejs-express-mongoose-demo